# How do I run the script automatically when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that outputs an alert if certain conditions are met (when entered directly into the browser console, it works). But `setTimeout()` or `window.onload` and `addEventListener` are not triggered. The code is located in the Google Chrome extension.

```
function Check_RM() {
    RM_number = $('#CasePageStnCaseNumberRMIntegerEdit-el').val()
    RM_number_full = RM_number.replace(/\s/g, '');
    check_length = new RegExp("[0-9]{6.6}+$").test(RM_number_full);
    check_number = new RegExp("[2,3,4]+$").test(RM_number_full);
    if (check_number) {
        alert('Заявка есть в Redmine');
    } else {
        console.log('Нет заявки')
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to show how you use `settimeout` and/or `window.onload` and/or `addEventListener`. And what do you mean by `The code is located in the Google Chrome extension`, did you create an actual browser extension and install it in into Chrome?

Comment: yes, 
the previous programmers left the extension and I support it

Comment: Could it be that the data is not yet present on the page when the script runs?

Comment: the data is actually loaded. but settimeout doesn't help. I don't even know how to do it

Comment: This question needs improvement in clarity and details. Otherwise is probable you wont receive help.

Comment: FYI: Your first regular expression is likely invalid. Did you mean `/[0-9]{6}$/`? Or is your value `0-9` followed by literally `{6.6}}}`? It is either a fixed `{count}` like shown or a `{from,to}` - like `[0-9]{1,6}$` for "1 to 6 numbers from 0 to 9 at the end of the string". In the next check only 2, 3, 4 are allowed in the number. Which one do you want? What does `console.log(RM_number);` output?